# Resolving " ${ is not a valid variable in fish" error when installing ghc (the Haskell compiler) on MacOs with fish

Tags: haskell, ghc

When following [these instructions](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/) for installing ghc, the installer presented me with this question.

```
Detected ~/.bashrc on your system...
If you want ghcup to automatically fix your ~/.bashrc to include the required PATH variable
answer with YES and press ENTER (at your own risk).
```

To which I responded "yes."

This added a file at `Users/admin/.ghcup/env` which was automatically set to be sourced by my `.bashrc` file. However, after sourcing my `.bashrc` file, the compiler was still not added to my `PATH` environment variable. So I tried sourcing `Users/admin/.ghcup/env` directly and got this error.

```
~/.ghcup/env (line 1): ${ is not a valid variable in fish.
export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:${GHCUP_INSTALL_BASE_PREFIX:=$HOME}/.ghcup/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: If you are using `fish`, why do you care about updating `.bashrc`? `fish` doesn't use it.

Comment: So the answer to that question is that I had been using bash for a long time before switching to fish. And so when I switched to fish, I sourced the bashrc file as well to bring in all of the aliases/whatnot from bash. I'm not doing that at all anymore and have switched to zsh

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.bashrc` with either `fish` or `zsh`. There's more overlap between `bash` and `zsh` than between `bash` and `fish`, but the two shells are different enough to warrant translating the file to a proper `.zshrc` file.

Comment: I'm not source .bashrc at all anymore, but thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has to do with the fish syntax for declaring variables. I was able to get it to work by simply changing the contents of `User/admin/.ghcup/env` to the following.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$HOME/.ghcup/bin:$PATH"
```