# Error: fish: ${ is not a valid variable in fish

Tags: shell, fish

So I'm trying to run this command to turn files into a .chd file:

```
for i in *.cue; do chdman createcd -i "$i" -o "${i%.*}.chd"; done
```

But I get this error:

```
fish: ${ is not a valid variable in fish.
for i in *.cue; do chdman createcd -i "$i" -o "${i%.*}.chd"; done
```

Which is boggling to me cuz I run this command to convert flac to ogg and it works just fine:

```
find . -name "*flac" -exec sh -c 'oggenc -q 7 "$1" -o ~/vorbis/"${1%.*}".ogg' _ {} \;
```

The second line uses `${` and works fine. So why is the first command giving me that error for `${`? I've searched around and can't find much on the subject. I'd really like to understand so if I use a similar string in the future I'll know what to do. I don't really know much about coding, so this really has my interest. And frustration at the same time.

What I have tried is replacing `${` with `$(`, and other variants. But nothing has worked. The command works fine in zsh, so it's something with Fish.

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57882337/resolving-is-not-a-valid-variable-in-fish-error-when-installing-ghc-the-h)

Looks like someone having a similar problem, but... do I really have to install something (ghc) to get this working? Seems like there would be a different work around.

Answer (score 5):

The proper `fish` version of that loop is:

```
for i in *.cue; chdman createcd -i $i -o (path change-extension chd $i); end
```

`fish` is *not* a Bourne-style shell like `sh` or `bash` or `zsh` and does not have the same syntax. Trying to treat it like it is in that family is of course not going work very well. You should read through its documentation if you're planning on using it for scripting. I'd start with [`fish` for `bash` users](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your second working command is running commands in a Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`); that's what the `-exec sh -c '...'` is for in your `find` command.

On the other hand, you're trying to run the first command directly in the `fish` shell. That's not going to work. You could explicitly run it using `/bin/sh`, just like in your `find` command:

```
sh -c 'for i in *.cue; do chdman createcd -i "$i" -o "${i%.*}.chd"; done'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do it in fish since OP is already running that shell, just using the correct syntax (Whatever that might be; I don't know fish)?

Comment: Sure; I was just addressing the question of why the command wasn't working.